# dijit.findWidgets return null array?

Tags: javascript, widget, reload, dojo

On the JSTL page I have following divs

```
<div dojoType="dijit.layout.TabContainer" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" doLayout="false" id="dojoTabbedPane" >
            <c:forEach items="${summariesMap}" var="summaryEntry">
                <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="${summaryEntry.key}">
```

I try to find all divs under (including dojoTabbedPane) in order to recersively destroy all the contentPane under it. Then I can use jQuery.load() to reload contents and use

```
dojo.parser.parse(dijit.byId("dojoTabbedPane"));
```

to re-parse the component to make sure the tabbedPane can be rendered(otherwise it doesn't and cause memory leak or error)

Here the question is: 
(1) Am I on the right track to re-parse the dojo TabbedContainer?
(2) Why each time the findWidgets function just return array with size 0?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: more specifically, dojo.parser.parse takes a DOM node.  You want ```dojo.byId``` or even the JQuery equivalent ```$```, not ```dijit.byId``` which returns a Widget JS Object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer 2 first: because dijit.findWidgets expects a DOM node, not a widget. If you need to find all widgets inside another widget, you can use getDescendants instead:

```
var descWidgets = dijit.byId("dojoTabbedPane").getDescendants();
```

Onto question 1: First off: if you want to destroy all the tabs in a TabContainer, you can use :

```
dijit.byId("dojoTabbedPane").destroyDescendants();
```

Now, if I understand you correctly, you subsequently grab a string of HTML from the server (using jQuery), and want to add it to the TabContainer. This new content contains several ContentPane divs, and you want these to become the new tabs in the TabContainer.

I may be wrong here, but I don't think that's doable without some gnarly hack. Once you've parsed/instantiated a TabContainer, you should add tabs using addChild, passing instantiated ContentPanes.

This means that if you get new HTML content like this from the server (via your jQuery load):

```
<div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="new tab1">foo</div>
<div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="new tab2">bar</div>
```

.. then your best bet is to remove the old TabContainer and make a new one, then parse the whole thing. If you're able to change the content you get from your server, perhaps you can simply wrap that in `<div dojoType="dijit.layout.TabContainer...`.

Comment: Thank a lot for the quick feedback. The requirement is actually simpler than that. There is a div with id "refreshable" which contains the tabContainer div, and it is actually the 'refreshable' need to reload by jQuery. The problem is, each time after the $jQuery reload the content, all the divs(say content panes) under the tabContainer show up in a stack(I guess it is because the tabContainer is not parsed or rendered). So I wonder how to fix that, may be destroy the tabContainer and everything under it before reload and then parse them after then? Please share any idea, thanks a lot

Comment: Ok. Yes, before you replace the content in the "refreshable" div, you should definitely destroy the TabContainer and its descendants. `dijit.byId("dojoTabbedPane").destroyRecursive()` should do the trick. Then, when you've added new content to the refreshable, you parse it with `dojo.parser.parse(dojo.byId("refreshable"));`

Comment: Thank you. Actually I tried but don't know why all contentPanes still show up on a stack without the tabs and container. Also very interesting found is that I use `var result = dojo.parser.parse(dojo.byId("refreshable"));` and output the result on an `alert('result')`, it seems each reload there is a new contentPane object is created(showing contentPane_x where x is keep increasing). So I guess maybe there is still memory leak because Dojo doesn't render the same object every reload but create new ones?

Comment: After finding id of all the contentPane within the tabContainer keeping increment after each reloading, I find out browser consuming more memory after each refreshing. Chrome get almost jump 1M each time, firefox is better, IE almost be stable for memory consumption. Can we say it is a memory leak? I have already put 'false' in the `dijit.byId("dojoTabbedPane").destroyRecursive(false)` so I guess all the containing contentPane within tabContainer should be destroyed by then?